# Target previous element with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm creating portfolio section where every portfolio item shows as an image and every portfolio item has its own div which is hidden and contains more information about that item. When the user clicks on some portfolio item (image) div with more information for that item is shown. Each div with more info has two classes, **portf-[nid]** and **portf** ([nid] is Node ID, I work in Drupal and this class with [nid] helps me to target portfolio item with more info div for that item).

Each of the more info divs contains arrows for item listing (next and previous) and I need to get them function, so when the user clicks on previous I need to hide current and show the previous item if it exists(when clicks on next to hide current and show next item if it exists).

My markup looks like:

```
<div class="portf-3 portf">
//some elements
</div>

<div class="portf-6 portf">
//some elements
</div>

<div class="portf-7 portf">
//some elements
</div>
```

My question is how to hide the div I'm currently on and show the previous (or next). For example: if it is currently shown div with class **portf-6** and user clicks on previous arrow, this div is being hidden and div with class **portf-3** is being shown.

It's not the problem to hide/show the div but how to check if there is the div above/below the current div and to target that div above or below the current div?

Comment: create a fiddle for this

Comment: please add your prev and next button html also and put code that you have tried so far

Comment: Note: You also need to disable the prev or next button when you hit the first/last entry. Please provide more of your HTML to get better answers :)

Comment: As the current answers are only accounting for the simplest case, I have added something to explain my previous comment. Enjoy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you are:

```
function GoToPrev()
{
   var isTheLast = $('.portf:visible').prev('.portf').length === 0;
   if(!isTheLast)
   {
      $('.portf:visible').hide().prev().show();
   }
}

function GoToNext()
{
   var isTheLast = $('.portf:visible').next('.portf').length === 0;
   if(!isTheLast)
   {
      $('.portf:visible').hide().next().show();
   }
}
```

Comment: Why introduce a extra negative (e.g. `!isTheLast`)? Just reverse the check.

Comment: `if ($('.portf:visible').prev('.portf').length)` is just as readable, shorter, and avoids adding a var (or a global in your case) :)

Comment: Thank you very much, that is what I looking for. Thanks @TrueBlueAussie, this is the better and shorter way...

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie, you are right, It shouldn't be a global :)

Answer (score 0):

To check if prev / next element is present or not, you can make use of `.length` property as shown below

`if($('.portf:visible').prev('.portf').length > 0) // greater than 0 means present else not`

same for next element

```
if($('.portf:visible').next('.portf').length > 0)
```

Comment: A simple boolean test will suffice when checking for 0/non-zero. `> 0` is not needed.

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie, yes you are right. I just put it so that OP should get clear idea and should not confused if not aware of `if(length)` code

Answer (score 0):

As you also need to update the next and previous buttons, I would suggest a more structured approach to the whole thing:

```
function update(delta) {
    var $portfs = $('.portf');
    var $current = $portfs.filter(':visible');
    var index = $portfs.index($current) + delta;
    if (index < 0) {
       index = 0;
    }
    if (index > $portfs.length){
        index = $portfs.length;
    }
    $current.hide();
    $portfs.eq(index).show();
    $('#prev').toggle(index > 0);
    $('#next').toggle(index < $portfs.length-1);
}

$('#prev').click(function () {
    update(-1);
});
$('#next').click(function () {
    update(1);
});

// Hide all initially
$('.portf').hide();
// Show the first with appropriate logic
update(1);
```

**JSFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/xp0peoxw/

This uses a common function that takes a delta direction value and makes the decisions on range capping an when to hide/show the next/previous buttons.

The code can be shortened further, but I was aiming for readability of the logic.

If the next/prev buttons are correctly shown the range checking is not needed, so it simplifies to:

```
function update(delta) {
    var $portfs = $('.portf');
    var $current = $portfs.filter(':visible');
    var index = $portfs.index($current) + delta;
    $current.hide();
    $portfs.eq(index).show();
    $('#prev').toggle(index > 0);
    $('#next').toggle(index < $portfs.length-1);
}
```

**JSFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/xp0peoxw/1/